# How to check effectively whether date is valid or not in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have three dropdown fields called `"Day"`, `"Month"` and `"Year"`. I have found so many way to check selected value from those dropdown are valid date in angularjs.

Here is data populated into three dropdown field.

```
    var numberOfYears = (new Date()).getYear() - 10;
    var years = $.map($(Array(numberOfYears)), function (val, i) { return i + 1900; });
    var months = $.map($(Array(12)), function (val, i) { return i + 1; });
    var days = $.map($(Array(31)), function (val, i) { return i + 1; });

    $scope.Years = years;
    $scope.Days = days;
    $scope.Months = months;
```

Please let me know how to check whether date is valid or not in AngularJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every dropdown onchange event you can check if date is valid or not as

```js
        function ValidateDate() {
          if (!isDate($('#dateid').val() + '/' + $('#monthid').val() + '/' + $('#yearid').val())) {
            alert('Date is not valid');
          }

        }

         //format(dd/MM/yyyy)
        function isDate(value) {
          var re = /^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-.\/])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$/;
          var flag = re.test(value);
          return flag;
        }
```

For more for check valid date follow [validate date in JQuery](http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/JAVAScript/JQuery/How-to-validate-date-in-JQuery/20223)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know weather it is helpful to you or not. but i just tried out

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.y = "1991";
  $scope.m = "2";
  $scope.d = "25";
  $scope.$watch('[y,m,d]', function() {
    var year = new Date($scope.m + "-" + $scope.d + "-" + $scope.y);
    if (year == "Invalid Date") {
      $scope.flag = false;
    } else {
      $scope.flag = true;
    }
  }, true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form>
    <select ng-model="y">
      <option val="1991">1991</option>
      <option val="1992">1992</option>
      <option val="c">c</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="m">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>a</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="d">
      <option>25</option>
      <option>26</option>
      <option>b</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <span>Valid : {{flag}}</span>
</div>
```